# has kotlin compiler a bug with plus operator?

Tags: kotlin

I like kotlin's `+=` syntax for lists.
Its a concise and intuitive notation.

But recently I discovered an edge case, where I suspect, the compiler is buggy.

`java.nio.file.Path` is defined recursively `public interface Path extends Iterable<Path>, ...`
And that seems to cause problems for `Iterable`'s `plus operator` in `kotlin-stdlib`.

```
private val abc = Path.of("/tmp/abc.txt")
private val def = Path.of("/tmp/def.txt")

@Test
fun `plus operator List Path`() {
    var list = emptyList<Path>()
    list += listOf(abc)
    list += def  // (*) should not compile

    list.asClue {
        // oops. red bar.
        it shouldBe listOf(abc, def)
    }
}
```

The test fails with:

```
Elements differ at index 1: [\tmp\abc.txt, tmp, def.txt]
```

In my opinion the line marked with `(*)` shouldn't even compile, since it is not clear which of the following overloads is intended

- [operator fun  Iterable.plus(element: T)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1b49105c78c566ec42b422cbd46782b47a0d9f40/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L3062)
- [operator fun  Iterable.plus(elements: Iterable)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1b49105c78c566ec42b422cbd46782b47a0d9f40/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L3104)

Notice that for `plusAssign operator` on `MutableList` compilation is rightly rejected.

```
@Test
fun `plusAssign operator MutableList Path`() {
    val list = mutableListOf<Path>()
    list += listOf(abc)
    // does not compile, which is good
    // list += def // (**)

    list shouldBe listOf(abc)
}
```

The line marked with `(**)` is ambiguous for

- [operator fun  MutableCollection.plusAssign(element: T)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1b49105c78c566ec42b422cbd46782b47a0d9f40/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/MutableCollections.kt#L51)
- [operator fun  MutableCollection.plusAssign(elements: Iterable)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1b49105c78c566ec42b422cbd46782b47a0d9f40/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/MutableCollections.kt#L59)

Comment: [Kotlin chooses the overload with the most specific type](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#choosing-the-most-specific-candidate-from-the-overload-candidate-set) so maybe a more direct way to phrase your question is "Why is `Iterable<T>` considered more precise than `T` rather than equally precise, which would make it ambiguous and cause a compiler error?"